# unattended-upgrades says packages have been kept back due to conffile prompt of apache2

Tags: 16.04, apache2, unattended-upgrades

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server in production that has unattended-upgrades running, and I am getting messages from the server saying that apache2 packages have been kept back:

```
Unattended upgrade returned: True

Packages that were upgraded:
 
Packages with upgradable origin but kept back:
 apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils 

Unattended-upgrades log:
Initial blacklisted packages: 
Initial whitelisted packages: 
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: ['o=Ubuntu,a=xenial', 'o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security', 'o=UbuntuESM,a=xenial']
Package 'apache2' has conffile prompt and needs to be upgraded manually
package 'apache2' not upgraded
package 'apache2-bin' not upgraded
package 'apache2-data' not upgraded
package 'apache2-utils' not upgraded
Packages that will be upgraded:
```

My unattended-upgrades configuration is as follows (only showing enabled settings):

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}";
};
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "myname@mydomain.com";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "07:00";
```

I'm not a linux expert at all (I'm an experienced developer though), so after looking around a bit on the internet, I found that there is most probably something that makes apache2 prompt for user imput related to changed configuration files.
I found a few posts

My question is two-fold:

1. How do I now manually do this update of apache2, still in a way that only security updates get installed (and possibly new packages if really needed for this update)? I'd like to understand what this conffile thing really is about?
2. What is the best way to make sure that if something goes wrong (for example to these configuration files), that I can still go back? What to backup? I can create a snapshot of the whole server via my Linode admin panel (and I will) but that feels like a "last resort" thing to do...

Also, is there a good way that I can try the same kind of update that unattended-upgrades would do (so only using the configured origins, without doing unnecessary other updates, only security updates, ...) but then manually, so I can get to actually see that prompt (and maybe see more info there)?

As said, this is for a live production server (not a local home machine), but I can afford to be offline for a few hours if needed.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, and hopefully you can help me with this.

Koen